# Stack organization in thread programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, stack

I am making primitive version of operating system in C++/assembly and my own Thread and PCB classes.

Every thread has it's own PCB where i can store context informations.
Every PCB(Process Control Block) has it's own stack:

```
unsigned stack[stackSize];
```

and

```
sp, ss and ss pointer:  
unsigned sp, ss, bp;
```

I should put wrapper method(calls run method of dedicated thread) on stack but i don't understand how will it be called.
(Run is not called in start() method because start only puts PCB in Scheduler)

I found this code:

```
    stack[stackSize - 1] = FP_SEG(thread);  
    stack[stackSize - 2] = FP_OFF(thread);  
    stack[stackSize - 5] = 0x200; //PSW, interrupt flag = 1  
    stack[stackSize - 6] = FP_SEG(Thread::wrapper);  
    stack[stackSize - 7] = FP_OFF(Thread::wrapper);
```

I don't understand why are these values saved to these spots in stack. What are speciffic rules for stack organization?

Answer (score 0):

The thread is created with new values for all those registers, which have to be saved somewhere with the thread so that the thread can be rescheduled. This is the place.

Comment: I understood that part. But why on this exact places, and how the wrapper method is called later on?

Comment: Well they have to be somewhere, and that's as good a place as any, right at the bottom of the stack. It doesn't matter as long as both ends agree. I don't know what 'wrapper method' you refer to.